# How can I block ads in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, adblock

I am looking for an ad blocker which works both in Internet Explorer 9 and all later versions. What options do I have?

I would prefer a solution that works without installing any 3rd party DLLs (something similar to 
[Adblock for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom)).

Comment: I've [updated my answer](http://superuser.com/a/329251/10259). [Adblock Plus (ABP) for Internet Explorer](https://adblockplus.org/en/internet-explorer) has been released. It should be able to use ABP ad blocking filter lists.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

IE's built-in [**Tracking Protection**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/tracking-protection) feature does ad blocking. No add-on needed.

You'll need to [subscribe to a Tracking Protection List](http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists). Your choices range from bad to good.

[galacticninja](https://superuser.com/users/10259/galacticninja) once pointed out that some Tracking Protection Lists block tracking content only, not just ads. But plenty of lists deal with ads:

- TRUSTe: bad. TRUSTe is a for-profit corporation; its list [overrides other lists and allows thousands of sources to bring in ads](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/privacy-protection-and-ie9-who-can-you-trust/3014). Do not subscribe.
- Abine: mediocre. Abine's lists have good star ratings there, but they don't block all ads. A line-count tool shows me that the "Abine Standard" list contains only a few hundred rules.
- EasyList Standard: good. This list has a lower star rating there, but is far better. It includes more than 8,000 rules. I suspect that users rated it only three stars there because it was designed only for ad blocking, not for privacy protection.

Comment: You can find a couple of TPL's (Tracking Protection Lists) to use for ad blocking here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/TrackingProtectionLists/ one from EasyList which the popular Adblock Plus uses too.

Comment: They added new lists since the last time I checked. It's working with the "EasyList Standard Tracking Protection List". Perfect, thanks!

Comment: Do TPL really works? I added some lists but all adverts continue to show...

Comment: @Velcro Try the [Fanboy AdBlock List](http://superuser.com/a/329251/10259) for Internet Explorer. It is designed to block ads, not tracking content (although ads and tracking content may overlap). It is limited to what IE's content blocker can block, though, and is not as effective (can't block as many ads) as the Fanboy List for AdBlock Plus in Firefox.

Comment: @kez and chris: The EasyPrivacy Tracking Protection List only targets blocking of tracking content, not ads (although ads and tracking content may overlap). It is not the same as [EasyList](http://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) for Adblock Plus in Firefox and Chrome. It is similar to [EasyPrivacy](http://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) for ABP in Fx and Chrome though, which also aims to block tracking content. Currently and AFAIK, only the [Fanboy Adblock List for Internet Explorer](http://superuser.com/a/329251/10259) specifically targets blocking of ads through IE's Tracking Protection feature.

Comment: @galacticninja My problem was due to Trend Micro Antivirus Internet Explorer BHO. Disabling it make TPL working like a charm. By the way I use this list: http://dayngo.com/static/filter.html

Answer (score 3):

Update: In 2013-08-13, [**Adblock Plus (ABP)** for Internet Explorer has been released.](https://adblockplus.org/releases/adblock-plus-10-for-internet-explorer-released) It uses [EasyList](https://easylist.to/), with an option to use it with one of the regional EasyList variants. Since this uses ABP syntax filter lists, it blocks ads better than the less effective IE Tracking Protection Lists.

[Adblock Plus for Internet Explorer](https://adblockplus.org/en/internet-explorer) download page

---

You can also use lists for IE's [Tracking Protection](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/iegallery) content blocker.

<sup>Note that this doesn't block as many ads as the filter lists used by ad blockers for other browsers (like Adblock Plus or uBlock Origin) due to limitations on how it can block content.</sup>

[**EasyList Standard**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/iegallery) and [**Fanboy Adblock List**](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/ie.html) are IE Tracking Protection lists designed to block ad content (which might not necessarily be trackers).

You might also want to use [EasyPrivacy Tracking Protection List](https://easylist.to/pages/other-supplementary-filter-lists-and-easylist-variants.html) and [Fanboy Tracking Protection List](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/ie.html). These are geared towards blocking trackers, which might not necessarily be ads.

Comment: It does not work either. (IE10)

Comment: @LWZ You can report that at [Fanboy's Adblock Forum](http://forums.fanboy.co.nz/forums/), maybe they can fix that.

Comment: @LWZ I've updated my answer. Try Adblock Plus for IE.

Answer (score 1):

Through a simple [Google search](http://www.google.se/search?q=ie9+ad+blocker&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy&hl=sv&client=firefox-a&hs=of7&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=ie9+adblock&aq=1&aqi=g-s1g2g-s1&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=b5f004ce8787582) I found that [Simple Adblock](http://simple-adblock.com/) seems to be working. And @grawity is right. You will have to install third party software.

Simple Adblock costs $29.95 for the uncrippled version.

I have not tried it myself but according to [Softpedia it's 100% clean](http://www.softpedia.com/progClean/Simple-Adblock-Clean-136526.html) ([and Brothersoft too](http://www.brothersoft.com/simple-adblock-288535.html)).

According to their own website they have **automatic filterupdates** and

> Simple Adblock blocks ads before they are downloaded by Internet Explorer and hides the occupied space with element hiding.

Comment: Could you also share your experience with it? e.g. does it block most ads? does it update automatically? can it be trusted or does it steal your banking login?

Comment: I have updated the answer with more information

Comment: Simple Adblock works well, however, it is no longer free. :( It costs $29.95 US, which is a bit steep considering Adblock Plus for Firefox and Chrome is $29.95 less expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the Easylist TPL and it did not remove the ads on some sites I use on a daily basis. However I found this one

http://www.quero.at/de/adblock_ie_tpl.php

(link is on the right) which is based on easylist and works great (at least for me)