# How can I block ads for free in IE10 (both modern UI and desktop)?

Tags: adblock, internet-explorer-10

I am looking for a free way to block ads for IE10. A way which works in both the Modern UI version as well as the desktop version.

I have found [Simple Adblock](http://simple-adblock.com/) but only the trial version is free.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Its not possible to use an add-on while using the Modern UI IE10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately nothing like this exists, but you can try to block ads the old fashioned way, with a HOST file. This is a special file that will block all traffic from domains that are suspected as being advertizements.  Detailed instructions on how to use the file can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/122404/how-to-block-websites-in-windows-8s-hosts-file/). 
Among my favorite block lists can be found [here](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/).

Answer (score 6):

If you [set it up in a special way](https://superuser.com/questions/257792/how-can-i-block-ads-in-internet-explorer-9-ie9), Internet Explorer's built-in Tracking Protection feature blocks ads -- and works even better than the HOSTS-file solution suggested in the answer Mikhail wrote.

Comment: An article on IE9 is not very helpful when the author is asking about IE10 and the Modern UI IE10.  The instructions would only be helpful for one of those.

Comment: AFAIK, this feature works great in IE10 in both Desktop and RT versions of Windows 8. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4):

IE has a built in ad blocker, you merely have to tell it which sites/adverts/cookies etc to block.
Fortunately these lists have already been made. Just browse to http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists and click add list and explorer will add it to the integrated ad blocker.

BTW, uses the same blocking lists (Easy-List) as ad-blocker on chrome

Comment: As far as I can see, this does not block ads but this tries to protect you from being tracked. That's not the same thing.

Comment: The name of the list is "Tracking Protection" this doesn't block ads.

Comment: It may be called tracking protection, but you can download additional lists from http://www.iegallery.com/en-us/trackingprotectionlists. You will see that there are different types of lists (e.g. privacy protection and Ad-blocking). I know it works because I use it every day and it removes ads from youtube, facebook and the like. Please don't mark my comment down without fully understanding what you write. Thanks, Steve

Comment: I installed the EasyList on IE10, but it's not blocking any ads.

Answer (score 0):

#### **[Adblock Plus (ABP)](https://adblockplus.org/en/internet-explorer)** for Internet Explorer

ABP for IE uses [EasyList](https://easylist.to/), an ad-blocking filter list, with an option to use it with one of the regional EasyList variants.  EasyList is the same filter list that is also used by default in ABP and uBlock Origin for Chrome and Firefox. Since it uses ABP syntax filter lists, it blocks ads better than the less effective IE Tracking Protection Lists, and HOSTS file based ad blocking.

Note: [Add-ons such as Adblock Plus can only be used in the desktop UI.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/17447/windows-internet-explorer-11-manage-add-ons)

Answer (score 0):

*While Internet Explorer should no longer be utilized as it's no longer supported and hasn't received a security update in ~3yrs, this applies to all browsers.*

---

[MVPS Hosts](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts2.htm) is the best solution I've come across that is regularly updated ([FAQs](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hostsfaq.htm)).

1. Download MVPS [hosts.zip](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.zip) and open
2. Extract `hosts` to `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc`

I also recommend adding the [Malware Domain List](https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt) *below* the MVPS hosts entries

1. Open `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Notepad as Administrator

   1. **<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>**
   2. **Open:** `notepad %WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
   3. While holding down **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** press **OK**

      - *This runs Notepad with Administrator privileges, which is required to edit the `hosts` files*
2. **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>** to go to EOF *(**E**nd **O**f **F**ile)*
3. Navigate to Malware Domain List [`hosts.txt`](https://www.malwaredomainlist.com/hostslist/hosts.txt) and copy it's contents

   - Select all: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>**, then copy: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>**
4. Paste: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>** to end of `%WinDir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and save: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>**